# Small current through a wire

Tags: electric-current

Hi I dont know a great deal about electronics but I wondering if anybody can help me. I am making a small experiment and I want to send a very small current through a thin bare wire. I was thinking of using a small AAA battery as the source and bare wire would be exposed to a liquid solution which in turn will react to the current.How can I create this without avoiding a short to the battery. Is it at all possible? Help much appreciated.
With thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple circuit you can approximate using Ohm's Law : $V = I \cdot R$, rearranging this formula you get $I = V/R$. So you have two options: reduce the voltage or increase the resistance. As you are using an AAA battery, increasing the resistance is your best option. Do this using a simple resistor, this will also stop battery from shorting.

Comment: Yes thank you so much I was thinking that was the solution a few hours after I posted..Thanks again Thomas